# Discrete math: proofs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For any three integers , , and , if  is divisible by  and  is divisible by , then  is divisible by .

definition: An integer  is divisible by an integer  with ≠0, denoted  | , if and only if there exists an integer  such that =.

Can anyone help, with this problem I don't know how to approach it should I use proof by cases where every number is odd or even. Should I use direct proof or indirect proof?

Comment: `if  is divisible by ` Then by definition $\,y = ax\,$ for some integer $\,a \ne 0\,$. `and  is divisible by ` Repeat the first step.

Comment: btw, this is the transitive property of division.

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is divisible by $y$, then $z=ay$ for some $a\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, $y$ is divisible by $x$, so $y=bx$ for some $b\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Substituing in the first equation, $z=a(bx)=(ab)x$, and $ab\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $z$ is divisible by $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is divisible by $x$, we have $y = kx$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$. And if $z$ is divisible by $y$, we have $z = my$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$. Now, putting $y = kx$ to $z = my$, we have $z = mkx$. Therefore by definition, $x|z$.